# Como usar onchange para um select dentro de um async await?

Tags: javascript, html-select, assincronismo, async-await

Tenho o seguinte código em HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Trunfo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select name="deck" id="deck">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Escolha um Trunfo</option>
    </select>
    <script src="./script.js" async></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

O seguinte código em JS:

```
async function loadData() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("./trunfos.json");
    const data = await response.json();
    manipulatingData(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

function manipulatingData(data) {
  let deckSelect = document.getElementById("deck");
  data.map((deck) => {
    let opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.value = deck.Trunfo;
    opt.innerHTML = deck.Trunfo;
    deckSelect.append(opt);
  });

  let selectDeck = document.getElementById("deck");
  selectDeck.setAttribute("onchange", function () {
    console.log("teste");
  });
}

loadData();
```

E um JSON, mas como é muito grande, não da para colocar aqui.
Eu gostaria de ao carregar as informações do async/await no json, mostrar os títulos no select (o que já está acontecendo) e ao trocar de opção, trocasse as informações carregadas.
Basicamente eu não estou conseguindo colocar o onchange para funcionar carregando uma função com o retorno do JSON. O retorno do JSON está dentro do ASYNC/AWAIT e dentro dele eu não consigo usar o onchange.

Comment: se a variavel `data` estiver no escopo global, em vez de `const data = await ...`  para `data = await response.json();`  a função anônima pegaria ?? `.setAttribute("onchange", function () {
    console.log(data);`

Comment: Assim? Não pegou

async function loadData() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("./trunfos.json");
    const data = await response.json();
    let deckSelect = document.getElementById("deck");
    data.map((deck) => {
      let opt = document.createElement("option");
      opt.value = deck.Trunfo;
      opt.innerHTML = deck.Trunfo;
      deckSelect.append(opt);
    });
    // deckSelect.setAttribute("onchange", function () {
    //   console.log(data);
    // });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

loadData();

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sobre a solução e o que ela ocasiona:

**"** *Mas isso me faz fazer várias requisições, recarregando as mesmas informações....* **"**

Para livrar-se das requisições, usa uma instancia global que representara a ausência intencional de qualquer objeto ou um array que poderá armazenar valores do **JSON** pode complementar o código nos dois recurso citados terá que ser filtrados.

Situação 1:

```
let data = null;

async function loadData() {
    [código original não alterado]
    const jSON_ = await response.json();
    data = jSON_;
    [código original não alterado]
```

Essa solução evitara o excesso de requisições,quando function `load()` é invocada sera uma unica requisição.
`loadData()` responsável pelos dados.

`load()` encarrega de verifica se tudo ja foi completado antes de uma nova requisição caso falhar  `loadData()` novamente.

`onchange` é inserida a `load` quando houver a ação os dados passara pela verificação

```
async function load() {
  if (!data) {
    await loadData();
  }
  let deckSelect = document.getElementById("deck");
  data.map((deck) => {
    let opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.value = deck.Trunfo;
    opt.innerHTML = deck.Trunfo;
    deckSelect.append(opt);
  });

  let selectDeck = document.getElementById("deck");
  selectDeck.onchange = function() {
    let deck = data.find((el) => el.Trunfo === selectDeck.value);
    console.log(deck.Cartas);
  };
}

load();
```

Como pode notar não ocorreu muitos ajustes apenas a ideia que mencionei que poderia ajudar.

Comment: Agora eu entendi. Muito obrigado! Eu ainda não entendi direito o motivo do setatributte não funcionar, pois acho que é a mesma ideia. Mas agora estou contente que vou conseguir manipular!

Answer (score -3):

Você pode simplesmente chamar o onChange no html mesmo. Exemplo:

```
<select name="deck" id="deck" onchange="onDeckChange()">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Escolha um Trunfo</option>
</select>
```

Depois é só criar uma função assíncrona que seria chamada toda vez que alterasse o valor do select, e dessa forma faria o preenchimento do select novamente:

```
async function onDeckChange(e) {
  await loadData(newUrl)
}
```

Porém eu não recomendo fazer alteração das opções do select no `onChange`, uma vez que todos os valores seriam alterados e o script perderia o estado da seleção atual. O ideal é carregar o select com suas opções já disponíveis de acordo com o retorno do json. Ou então talvez criar um botão que atualize as opções do select quando o usuário quiser que o faça. Assim o usuário teria ciência de que as opções disponíveis seriam atualizadas e que a opção que foi selecionada anteriormente seria perdida.

Comment: Outra situação não proveitosa, sempre que  chamar o `onDeckChange` as  opções vão ser alteradas  e não vai conseguir manter o  estado atual da seleção.

Answer (score -3):

consegui dessa forma:

```
 <select name="deck" id="deck" onchange="alterar()">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Escolha um Trunfo</option>
    </select>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
```

```
async function loadData() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("./trunfos.json");
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

async function load() {
  let data = await loadData();
  let deckSelect = document.getElementById("deck");
  data.map((deck) => {
    let opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.value = deck.Trunfo;
    opt.innerHTML = deck.Trunfo;
    deckSelect.append(opt);
  });
}

load();

async function alterar() {
  let selectDeck = document.getElementById("deck").value;
  let data = await loadData();
  let deck = data.find((el) => el.Trunfo === selectDeck);
  console.log(deck.Cartas);
}
```

Mas isso me faz fazer várias requisições, recarregando as mesmas informações.
Eu gostaria de deixar as informações carregadas e depois usar a função on change pra filtrar mediante ao que eu já tenho.

Porém não estou conseguindo deixar nem de forma global e nem colocar uma setattribute dentro da função de load.

Comment: Dessa forma vai sobre carregar deixa muito lento e não trem praticidade nenhum.

Comment: Creio que poderia resolver dessa forma , mas meu comentário anterior era referente ao acesso global e não epenas local.